# What is the `app://` scheme that is used for assets in Webpack-5-built apps in dev mode?

Tags: javascript, webpack, browser, url-scheme

In my Webpack 5-built app, when in the `development` mode, I've seen the browser request assets using a URL with an `app://` scheme. Here's an example:

```
app:///node_modules/dir/to/package/index.js
```

For those apps, I also saw the actual tree under `app://` in the `Debugger` tab of the `devtools`, under `Sources`:

[image]

I noticed that this `app://` tree only shows under `Sources` when the build is in the `development` mode (the app uses Webpack 5), so it does *seem* related to Webpack, but I can't find anything in the Webpack docs about it.

In fact, it seems almost impossible to find anything online about `app://` (which is quite intriguing!), so I suspect it is indeed Webpack-specific and just badly/not documented.

Does anyone know anything about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `app://` is just the name that indicates where your code is being served to for you to get access. Also, you can change where the files are served by modifying the webpack configuration file. [webpack-dev-server docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)

For example, here's a screenshot of a project that I'm working on which starts the static server instance on `localhost:3000`, allowing me to get access to the compiled files of the project.

[image: localhost]